# how to convert datetime format in NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have got value from the xml `2009-11-23T05:24:41.000Z`.

Now i want to display string like this: `Wed, Nov 4, 2009 8:00 PM - Wed, Nov 4, 2009 9:00 PM`

How it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter * inputFormatter = [ [ [ NSDateFormatter alloc ] init ] autorelease ];
NSDateFormatter * outputFormatter = [ [ [ NSDateFormatter alloc ] init ] autorelease ];
[ inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000Z'" ];
[ outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d, yyyy h:mm a" ]; 

NSString * inputString = @"2009-11-23T05:24:41.000Z";
NSDate * inputDate = [ inputFormatter dateFromString:inputString ];
NSString * outputString = [ outputFormatter stringFromDate:inputDate ];

// outputString = @"Mon, Nov 23, 2009 05:24 AM"
```

See the [Unicode date format patterns guide](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for more information on how to configure `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect. The format for the `inputFormatter` needs to be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `NSDateFormatter`'s methods `-dateFromString:` and `-stringFromDate:`.