# How change the date format which is stored in string? Objective c

Tags: iphone, datetime, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert datetime format in NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076417/how-to-convert-datetime-format-in-nsstring)

I have stored date in string from json parsing. The format of date is 2011-1-24. Now i want to convert into MM-dd-YYYY format. For that i am using this code

```
NSString *stringDate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[list_date objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
NSDate *date  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
NSString *newDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

But it show null value. What is problem in this code?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is different from @Mayur Joshi's answer though it looks to be same.

This is sure to work for you.

```
 NSString *dateString = @"2011-09-19";
 NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
 NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:dateString];
 [format setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
 NSString* finalDateString = [format stringFromDate:date];
 [format release];
```

I hope this helps you.

If you need any help on this then please leave a comment below.

Also you can refer to this link for more help. This link is really similar to what you want, only the target date Format is different.

[How to convert date string into format "17 Nov 2010"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203627/how-to-convert-date-string-into-format-17-nov-2010)

Comment: @Mayur: 'YYYY' is replaced with small 'yyyy' which stands for the Year.All I can say is  that 'YYYY' does not work. Also duplicate  declaration of NSString is removed. It is the basic concept which was wrongly displayed though your intention may not be wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *dateStr = @"2011-1-24";

 //OR if you have date then declare dateStr like this, 
 NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",yourDate];

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-M-dd"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY"];
 NSString* temp = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
 [dateFormat release];

 NSLog(@"%@",temp);
```

Comment: This code will also return *nil* as the date format for `dateFromString` should be `YYYY-M-dd`.

Comment: @Mayur: This is Wrong.. NSString *dateStr will generate compiler warning as it is declared twice..

Comment: @Parth :- Obviously there's an OR Option between both the NSString *dateStr, as one is simple text while other one is the case where you have date as input.

Comment: @EmptyStack :- okay thanks for that.. but i had kept the date as YYYY-MM-dd format only. Still, updating the answer.

Comment: @Mayur: This solution does not work.. I have tried it myself but still not working.

Comment: @parth : this works cz i tried and then posted. Wonder what you are doing wrong?

Comment: @Mayur: I still dont know how it works for you.

Comment: did you paste my code and run it? Does it show Null?