# IOS time, not work correctly

Tags: ios, time

I have a problem, i want make a date for local notify from a string. 
I make this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateForm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateForm setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateSelected = [dateForm dateFromString:@"2012-09-01 08:00:00"];
NSLog(@"notify time: |%@| \n", dateSelected);
```

but the log is:
 notify time: |2012-09-01 06:00:00 +0000| 
the time is wrong! Why? tanks for help!
I use iOS 5.1 and xcode 4.4

Comment: Located in western Europe (GMT+2) by any chance? That would make the result correct since it's presented in GMT.

Comment: the NSDateFormatter uses your local timezone, the NSLog uses UTC. You are from a country that uses the UTC+0200 timezone, europe probably.

Comment: ok thanks, i have understand. Yes, I write from Italy.

Comment: try to this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466801/how-change-the-date-format-which-is-stored-in-string-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
[dateForm setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
```

or

```
[dateForm setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

And replace `GMT` with your timezone.